# Compare the source and target files and put them into a single Excel spreadsheet with different sheets

Tags: talend

I have csv files and I need to compare the differences and load in target (excel) in 1 excel I need source is not in target, target is not in source, source difference, target difference, and I need logic for tmap..and excel difference sheet.

Can anyone help me for this question.

[image]

I tried like these.
overall recording is loading in target, but I need target like difference in source one sheet, difference in target 1 sheet like that.in one excel.

Comment: Without you data schema and an idea of what you want in output, it will be complicated to answer. But you can join your two files in a tMap if you have a common key in the two sources. you can also use the tMap variables to compare fields.